# Check if Substring is in string more than once?

Tags: c, file, parsing, pointers

Let's say I've got a file:

```
f56,5 d23,4
```

And I'm Getting the values after the 'f' and the comma (and the same thing with the d) so I do this:
(While reading in the file using fgets)

```
while (fgets(buf,100,file) != NULL)
{
    temp = strstr(buf,"f"); //where temp is a (char * )
    if(temp != NULL)
    {  
        //An int defined previously 
        x = atol(temp+1); //get the value 56
        temp = strstr(buf,","); //get the value 5
        y = atol(temp+1); //get the value 5
    }

    temp = strstr(buf,"d");
    if(temp != NULL)
    {
        a = atol(temp+1); //get the value 24
        temp = strstr(buf,","); //get the value 4?
        b = atol(temp+1); //get the value 4?
    }


}
```

This sort of works, however, the value of a and b aren't correct, a is sometimes true, however b is always the value of y (previous comma value). I'm not really sure how to proceed here, I've tried using another pointer to use `strstr` within the code but that doesn't seem to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however `b` is always the value of `y` (previous comma value)

This is because you are starting to search for the comma from the beginning again, so instead of getting the comma associated with `'d'` you get one associated with `'f'` again.

To fix this problem, replace this line

```
temp = strstr(buf, ","); //get the value 4?
```

with this:

```
temp = strstr(temp+1, ","); //yes, get the value 4!
```

This will start searching for the next comma after `'d'`, giving you the proper result.

Comment: Did you mean it would get the value 4 here? not 5?

Comment: @user3739406 Yes, you will get `4`.